# How to stream a resource with Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I want to connect to an external webserver that offers pdf resources. Those I want to stream directly as a response in my webserver.

My goal is to directly stream the resource that I receive. Including all the headers that I receive from the remote call (like `content-length`, `content-type`, `expires`, `filename`, etc). So my webservice is more like a proxy, hiding the real http call.

But how can I achieve that best? Probably the new `WebClient` class might be suitable here, similar to?

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
   @GetMapping("/files")
   public Resource getFile(@RequestParam String filename, UserAuthentication auth) {
          return webClient.get().uri("http://remote.api/{file}", filename).exchange().block();
   }
}
```